# placing a Vector in a Scatterplot - Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, optimization, seaborn

I had used an optimization algorithm to do a binary classification. The algorithm had produced a hyperplane (vector or list) that separates the classes of a dataset into two. Now, I wish to include this hyperplane (vector) in the scatterplot of the dataset. I need a guide on this, please.

Suppose the dataset is `X_test` with label as `y_test`. If the vector is say, `hyper = [a, b, c, d]`

I have my scatterplot as:

```
sns.set_style('white')
sns.scatterplot(X_test[:,0],X_test[:,1],hue=y_test.reshape(-1));
```

I could actually use the above seaborn or matplotlib for the scatterplot. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is very confusing by what exactly you mean by hyperplane here.  What are `a, b, c, d`? Are they an equation of a 3D plane? How does such a plane relate to your 2D scatter plot? It could help if you added code about how the hyperplane coordinates are created.

Comment: The hyperplane is only a vector with coordinates as a, b, c, d. I could replace the word hyperplane with say a vector defined as hyper = [a b c d]. The dimension of the hyperplane(4) is the same as that of dataset

Comment: Well, in case you can't describe what exactly your parameters mean, it is hard to help. A general solution for N dimensions doesn't seem feasible.  In 2D you can plot a line over the scatter plot wih `plt.plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1])`.